# How to use a Stage or anything inside the stage from outside the start method?

Tags: java, javafx, syntax

I am completely new to javafx.
It would probably be helpful enough to know why the code below is not working. (line 31: pw cannot be resolved)
But it would be nice to also know what else I might be doing wrong or inefficiently.
The end goal at some point is to have it draw a picture per-pixel on the screen.
What that picture is is however not so certain, and I'd like to be able to add pixels to that image from multiple different classes.
Also a possibility of adding some sort of more traditional UI on top, but that's not priority.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;

public class Render extends Application {

    public static void render(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Placeholder Title");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280, 720);
        Group root = new Group(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        PixelWriter pw = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();
        stage.show();
    }

    private static void testRender() {
        int c = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++, c--) {
                pw.setArgb(x, y, c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific with "not working" - e.g.: what is happening (that shouldn't be happening), what did you expect to happen, did you receive any errors, if yes what were they (exact error message and line)...

Comment: As for "how to use `Stage` outside of `start`" you could either store it in a separate class member variable or explicitly pass it to the function you are calling that needs to use it.

Comment: @UnholySheep, the program runs, but I can't use the testRender method anywhere because it's trying to use the PixelWriter that "cannot be resolved". Nothing can be resolved - I can't use anything I declared inside the start method.

Comment: That is because, as you said, you have it declared (locally) in the start method. If you want to access it in another method you need to either pass it explicitly (as a parameter to that method) or store it in a class member variable.

Comment: [What, something like this?](http://pastebin.com/RkPR63gG) Eclipse no longer says that anything's wrong, but suddenly [nothing works anymore](http://pastebin.com/8QFVSnRh).

Comment: No, don't try to initialize them in the constructor. Just keep the member variables but instead assign them in the `start` method (the `new` lines). I feel like your problem has little to do with JavaFX itself and is more of a basic Java problem, how to work with variables, class members and function parameters. Maybe you should try reading up on that. (Also nothing except your `render` method should need to be `static` as far as I can tell)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not experienced, no, but I think I can do basic Java stuff. If I create the variables outside the method, and assign values inside the method, then it tells me I can't make a static reference to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my explanations in comments seem to be unclear I'll try to explain by modifying the code (not tested, I'll try to help with any errors that it might contain).

Option 1: Storing the accessed variables as class members:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;

public class Render extends Application {

    private PixelWriter pw;

    public static void render(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Placeholder Title");
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280, 720);
        Group root = new Group(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        pw = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();
        testRender(); // we can't call this before everything has been initialized anyway
        stage.show();
    }
    // this doesn't need to be static
    private void testRender() {
        int c = -1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++, c--) {
                pw.setArgb(x, y, c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2: Passing the accessed instances as parameters:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Placeholder Title");
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1280, 720);
    Group root = new Group(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    PixelWriter pw = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();
    testRender(pw);
    stage.show();
}

private static void testRender(PixelWriter pw) {
    int c = -1;
    for (int x = 0; x < 1280; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 720; y++, c--) {
            pw.setArgb(x, y, c);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you understand your possible solutions

Comment: Right, those examples work, but if I were to want to use pw from some other class, option 2 wouldn't really work, and even if I set pw to public, I still can't make static references to it.

Comment: If you want to access these variables from other classes you'd need to think of a proper architecture (e.g.: having a singleton that stores and manages all the variables/instances you need and makes them accessible to different classes)

Comment: The `start()` method is the entry point to the application (i.e. essentially the first method that is called). So if any other classes you write depend on these values (such as `pw`, for example), you can pass those values to the objects you create from those classes. Those instances must ultimately be created in the `start()` method, or in methods called from `start()`, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can reffer this link to getting started with JavaFX.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/

Comment: I looked at those, but they're not all that related to what I'm trying to do, and as far as I can tell, they do everything inside the start method.

Comment: You have to just declare PixelWriter object before @Override notation.

Comment: That other answer of yours just plain doesn't compile. You can't instantiate it like that.